# How do I get nssm.exe log from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, subprocess, nssm

So I have been manually adding the path to log.txt file that nssm.exe logs it's activity to, now I want to add the file path via python.

I tried some code but got this **error**:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: returned a non-zero exit status 1
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
subprocess.check_output([nssm_path, 'log', service_path, '>', log_path], shell=True)
```

and also this one separately

```
subprocess.check_output([nssm_path, 'log', service_name, log_file_path], shell=True)
```

but still got the same error

Summary: **I want to tell nssm.exe to log it's activity to a txt file**
I need suggestions, please